# Como exibir dois TextBox a partir de um resultado no DropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Eu exibo um DropDownList com dois valores SC e PR, se ele seleciona SC então eu quero que exiba dois TextBox, um com o RG, e outro com a Data de Nascimento, e se a pessoa seleciona PR, eu quero de desça somente um campo com a Data de Nascimento e ele não pode ser menor de idade.

Estou fazendo em C# MVC, e estou com uma dúvida de como se faz em Jquery, JavaScript, ou outra solução.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumindo que vc já tem jquery incorporado a sua página.

Os campos:

```
<select name="campoSelecao" id="campoSelecao">
  <option value="SC">SC</option>
  <option value="PR">PR</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="inputRg" id="inputRg" style="display: none">
<input type="text" name="inputDtNascimento" id="inputDtNascimento" style="display: none">
```

Arquivo .js

```
$('body').on('change', '#campoSelecao', function () {
            $('#inputRg').css('display','none');
            $('#inputDtNascimento').css('display','none');

            var valorSelecionado = $(this).val();
            if (valorSelecionado == 'SC') {
                $('#inputRg').css('display','block');
                $('#inputDtNascimento').css('display','block');
            }

            if (valorSelecionado == 'PR') {
                $('#inputDtNascimento').css('display','block');
            }
    });
```

Para checar a idade:

1 - Eu sugiro o uso de um plugin de data, por exemplo: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ .Com esse plugin implementado, teremos o campo data formatado;

2 - Adicione o plugin moment.js https://momentjs.com/ . Esse plugin tornara qualquer comparação mais fácil;

3 - Implemente a regra no seu arquivo .js

```
$('body').on('focusout', '#inputDtNascimento', function () {
   var nascimento = $(this).val(); //pega a valor do campo data
   var idade = Math.floor(moment(new Date()).diff(moment(nascimento), 'years', true));
   if (idade < 18) {
      $(this).focus(); //da o foco no campo
      $(this).val(''); //limpar o campo
   }
});
```